# How do I restore a zope database from a .fsz file?

Tags: plone, restore, zope, zodb

I have a test environment which I am trying to restore my data into. I backed up my live site using repozo, but the zope documentation has disappeared on their new site.

This is the command I am trying:

```
/home/adrigen/atf/bin/repozo --recover --output=/home/adrigen/atf/var/filestorage/Data.fs --repository=/home/adrigen/atf/var/filestorage/backup/
```

This command completes without any failure message, but the data doesn't appear in plone (3).

Are there any tips or articles which will help me do this?

Comment: Tip: http://old.zope.org is the old site, so should be able to find your docs there.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The command looks fine at first glance, so perhaps something else is wrong. You did stop the zope instance first, and if this is a zeo setup you did stop the zeo server first?

If you have the .fsz file, then you can also use standard unzipping tools. The .fsz file is simple a gzipped file.  It may help to rename it to .fs.gz, otherwise some tools will refuse to work as the file does not have the expected extension.

I like to do it like this:

```
gzcat mybackup.fsz > var/filestorage/Data.fs
```

or similarly:

```
cat mybackup.fsz | gunzip > var/filestorage/Data.fs
```

Comment: No I didn't stop it. I thought repozo was for a **hot / running**  restore. Perhaps that is only true for backup. I wasn't aware that I could just uncompress and replace the file either. Thanks.

Comment: Seem to have got me to a different point. I have to contend with     "raise FileStorageFormatError(name)". I assume I've downloaded a corrupt file somehow.

Comment: repozo is for hot backup.  For restore: if the zeoserver is still using the Data.fs file at the moment, then it is a bad idea to restore to that same file at the moment.  If you cannot afford much down time, then it is of course fine to restore to a different file, stop the zeoserver, rename that different file to Data.fs and start the zeoserver again.